# Image not getting displayed

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Am having a problem in displaying the image?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: _app.ApplicationURL.BaseURL + 'Login/GetLoginUser?userName=' + username,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#lblLogin").css('background-image', 'url(' + data + ')');
    }
});
```

the data contains the image but its not getting displayed. Please help me on this.

Comment: two things: 1) whats your ajax return for data (console.log(data);)? 1) could you please past your html code also?

Comment: Its the image name in the (data) and am not doing anything in the html page **Satpal*

Comment: so you see the image URL in your console network tab? i asked for html because you may have problem on your html section(it is possible that you don't have lblLogin).

Comment: maybe image is in different directory than js file

Comment: does lblLogin contains height and width, since you are using backgroung-image the container should be block and also make sure the path of the image is correct

Comment: display value of data and check weather it is empty or not

Comment: #lblLogin

{
    float: left;
    background: url(./UserProfileImages/defaultimage.png) no-repeat;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background-size: 26px 26px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    display: block;
}
  this is my css.    *Omidam81* , **Chris** , **Snm**